# Query Minecraft Server with x10hosting

Tags: php, mysql, minecraft

I am trying to query a minecraft server for a website I'm making. I am using x10hosting. The problem is, it always returns "Offline". Here is my code:

```
<?php
        $status = @fsockopen("208.115.225.131", 25701, $errno, $errstr, 3);

        if($status)
        {
            echo 'Online';
        } else {
            echo 'Offline';
        }

    ?>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: the problem with your invisible code is ...

Comment: errno and errstr are probably there for a good reason...

Comment: It says - Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 208.115.225.131:25701 (Connection timed out) in /home/minernat/public_html/index.php on line 348 - Though the information is 100% correct.

Comment: "put on hold as off-topic" - This is wrong and misleading: "describe the specific problem."  That is very well described here: 'it always returns "Offline"' -- and "include valid code" - that's valid PHP, is it not?

Comment: Terribly sorry, this is my first question. I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that x10hosting firewalls free users on the outbound ports that they can connect to.  Port 25701 does not appear to be allowed.

Comment: Thanks, where can I find the full list of allowed outbound ports?

Comment: ask the host. when you pay nothing, don't expect to get much

Comment: Thanks for all the help :D I've decided to just use AJAX to read an XML file updated by the server. Any tips on doing this?

Comment: @SirFaizdat: Now, that might be a valid question "describe the specific problem" and "include valid code." Consider asking a new question, but being very specific about the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Aye sorry, this is my first question. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: Actually, I think your original question's fine.  I think the "put on hold" is wrong/outdated.  Your second one ("Any tips on doing this?"), if you want answered, should go into a separate question, but it will definitely need to be worded in a S.O.-friendly way.